# Range Slider WebService Call

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have double ended slider. On updated value of slider we want to call a Webservice.I want to call min and max final value but they call for everyvalue tracing in path .I am edited this this code work first time but after they not work. because the method is static once. Is there any method which call exactly once on method call.

```
- (void)report:(RangeSlider *)sender {
     NSString *rupee=@"\u20B9";
    min=slider.min *1000;
     max=slider.max *1000;

    minValue =(int)min;
    maxValue =(int)max;


    NSString *report = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d - %@ %d",rupee, (int)min,rupee, (int)max];
    reportLabel.text = report;
    reportLabel.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];


    NSString *email=     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"token"];
    NSString *ids=     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"id"];



       static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
    double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        if ([searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSDictionary *dict=[WebService searchByPrice:ids :email :minValue :maxValue];
            responseArray =[dict objectForKey:@"result"];

            NSLog(@"%@",responseArray);


            [table reloadData];


        }
    });

});


}
```