# Range Slider Event Value change

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a range slider UIControl class. On drag, the `report` method is called for every value. I only want the `report` method called once when the user finishes dragging. I am stuck in this code please help.

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(report:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

For more getting info 
[Range Slider WebService Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966159/range-slider-webservice-call)

Comment: Not clear what you asking

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot My report method call every value of slidermove.But i want to call this method on last value.where slider stop draging.

Answer (score 3):

`UISlider` has a `continuous` property. Set it to `NO` and you'll get a callback only when the user has lifted the finger. [From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISlider/continuous):

> If `YES`, the slider sends update events continuously to the associated
>   target’s action method. If `NO`, the slider only sends an action event
>   when the user releases the slider’s thumb control to set the final
>   value.
>
> The default value of this property is `YES`.

Comment: I am using Range Slider not UISlider

Comment: @varun which class is this?

Answer (score 0):

[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(report:) forControlEvents:UIControlTouchUpInside];

Answer (score 0):

So, as you yourself stated below (in a very brief 'answer' :) ), you might want to catch the event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`, which is sent in the touchesEnded-method of your control:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        trackingSlider = nil; //we are no longer tracking either slider
}
```

So you might wanna change

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(report:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

to

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(report:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I haven't tested it, but I think that should be the way to go...

#### EDIT:

Meanwhile, I've tested it, and it is the way to go. It would be nice to get some upvotes for correct answers, I can't wait to finally be able to comment on other people's answers :)